# Design pattern for decouple service layer with controller layer best practice Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns

I have a multiple services in my layer service, i have to execute some methods but each method in different service.

`MyLastService` have a lot of functions and Autowired services example of my `MyLastService` service :

```
@Service
class MyLastServiceImp implement MyLastService{
  @Autowired
  ProductService productService;

  @Autowired
  OrderService orderService; 

  @Autowired
  UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  ReferentialService referentialService;

  void addNewOrder(MyRequest req) {
    try {
     Product p = productService.findProduct(req.getProductId());
     User u = userService.findUserByUserName(req.getUserName()); 
     City c = referentialService.findCity(req.getCity());
     orderService.addOrder(p, u, c);
   }
    catch(Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("error : {}", e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

I am not satisfied with this implementation, beacause i will have a lot of other services and make all in one service `MyLastService` can make my code difficult to read and maintenable. That why i search currently a design pattern for my application.

What can happen to `MyLastService` if i put all other services into him ? 
My idea now is to add new layer but i don't know what ? 
Any one can propose to me the best practice for this use case ?

Answer (score 0):

You did good on not create dependency from one service to another.

In cases like these, you should use, in my opinion, a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

In your case, this Facade would be something like `OrderFacade`. This Facade then would do just what you're doing right there in the code you've posted

Comment: Thanks @Matheus Cirillo , I can't see any advantage of using facade in my use case at the end i need to create facadeService and Autowired all necessery services i don't want this, but i want like factory i think !!

Comment: Why would you use a Factory in this situation?